# MDX - Caption for a set of children

Tags: powerbi, ssas, mdx

I'm a SQL guy getting pulled into setting up an SSAS cube and pulling it into PowerBI. I'm experimenting with MDX, and have run into something I haven't been able to find an answer for.

**Scenario**

I have a huge table full of data captured from our SQL Server cohort, and I'm using this to inform a decomposition tree showing a measure and then breaking it down by *Instance Name, Server Name, Database Name, Client Hostname* and *Application Name*. My starting MDX query is:

```
SELECT 
{[Measures].[CPU]} ON COLUMNS,
{(
    [Profile Data].[Instance Name].children
  , [Profile Data].[Server Name].children
  , [Profile Data].[Database Name].children
  , [Profile Data].[Host Name].children
  , [Profile Data].[Application Name].children
)} ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube]
```

Pretty simple, right? And the actual result is what I need it to be - the sum of CPU time in milliseconds over the capture period, aggregated by the five attributes.

**The Problem**

When running the MDX query in SSMS, I get a nice caption for my CPU column, and nothing for my 5 aggregators. When I run the same query in Power BI I get a slightly more information column name:

```
[Profile Data].[Instance Name].[Instance Name].[MEMBER_CAPTION]
```

And so on for the other four. What I'd like is to be able to control that member caption, whether that's in the Dimension/Cube, or just in the MDX query.

**What I've Tried**

I've tried declaring them as calculated sets like:

```
SET [Instance Name] AS [Profile Data].[Instance Name].children
```

And even tried appending:

```
SET [Instance Name] AS [Profile Data].[Instance Name].children, CAPTION = 'Instance Name'
```

To no avail. I suspect the actual answer lies somewhere in the SSAS database. Each Attribute has a caption in the default language, but I have no idea how to go about setting a caption for the members/children.

Any direction would be much appreciated.